# Is there a nice expression that encapsulates the solution to all three cases of the Sturm-Liouville problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

When encountering a second-order linear ODE with an unknown constant, such as $X'' = \lambda X$, it is typical to traverse the three cases where $\lambda$ is positive, negative, and zero separately.  However, the positive and negative cases are easy to express together, since linear combinations of $e^{-\sqrt{\lambda} x}$ and $e^{\sqrt{\lambda} x}$ could be exponential or sinusoidal depending on $\lambda$.

However, I cannot think of a way to incorporate the extra powers of $x$ introduced by the resonance in the $\lambda = 0$ case into the same solution.  Is there a way to incorporate this case into a single, caseless expression for the solution to such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can form a basis of solutions:
$$
           X''=\lambda X,\;\;\; X(0)=0, X'(0)=1 \\
           Y''=\lambda Y,\;\;\; Y(0)=1, Y'(0)=0
$$
The solutions are
$$
              X_{\lambda}(x)=\frac{\sinh(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}},\;\; Y_{\lambda}(x)=\cosh(\sqrt{\lambda}x).
$$
$X_{\lambda}$ remains valid for $\lambda=0$ in the limit as $\lambda\rightarrow 0$, where the result is $X_0(x)=x$. This is generally true because the solutions for fixed conditions will vary analytically in $\lambda$, which means that the special cases hold in the limit. The solutions for fixed conditions are holomorphic in $\lambda$.

Comment: Do the initial conditions then have to remain fixed for the logic to hold, or can we use this answer to say that the general solution to $X'' = \lambda X$ is $X = A (\lim_{s \to \lambda} \frac{\sinh(\sqrt{s} x)}{\sqrt s}) + B(\lim_{s \to \lambda} \cosh(\sqrt{s} x))$ for any $\lambda$?

Comment: The general solution is $X(x)= X'(0)X_{\lambda}(x)+X(0)Y_{\lambda}(x)$.

Comment: Don't the limits have to remain in the general solution to handle the case of $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: @user10478 : Just define $X_0(x)=x$. $Y_0(x)=1$ is already okay.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose suitable linear combinations, you can have a set of basis solutions where the case $\lambda=0$ is included as limit, e.g.:
$$\lim_{\lambda\to0}\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x}+e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x}\right)=1$$
$$\lim_{\lambda\to0}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\lambda}}\left(e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x}-e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x}\right)=x$$.

Comment: So then the simplest, single case way to write the general solution to $X'' = \lambda X$ would be $X = A\lim_{s \to \lambda}(e^{\sqrt{s} x}+e^{-\sqrt{s} x}) + B \lim_{s \to \lambda}\frac{e^{\sqrt{s}x}-e^{-\sqrt{s}x}}{\sqrt{s}}$?  Or are you saying that using your expressions is only possible if the problem comes with exactly the right initial conditions to make the arbitrary constants equal to what you need them to be?

Comment: Also, something I find very strange about your expressions.  The thing inside the first limit is $cosh(\sqrt{\lambda} x)$ and the limit produces $1$.  The thing inside the second limit is the antiderivative of $cosh(\sqrt{\lambda} x)$, and the limit produces the antiderivative of $1$, but it doesn't seem to hold that the second antiderivative of $cosh(\sqrt{\lambda} x)$ produces even a constant multiple of $\frac{1}{2}x^2$ as $\lambda$ approaches $0$.

Comment: @user10478: Antiderivatives are defined only up to integration constants. A possible choice for the second antiderivative of $\cosh(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$ that is comparable with $\frac{1}{2}x^2$ for $\lambda\to0$ is $\frac{\cosh(\sqrt{\lambda}x)-1}{\lambda}$ and indeed $\lim_{\lambda\to0}\frac{\cosh(\sqrt{\lambda}x)-1}{\lambda}=\frac{1}{2}x^2$.

Comment: @user10478: Concerning your other comment: the other answer shows how the set of solutions can be fixed by initial conditions. Of course, other initial conditions can be imposed, even some depending on $\lambda$, as long as they are well-defined for each $\lambda$. This gives then other sets of basis solutions depending on $\lambda$, but for these sets to depend continuously on $\lambda$ it is (at least) necessary that the imposed initial conditions also depend continuously on $\lambda$.